# Equation on the vertices of regular polyhedra

Tags: representation-theory, polyhedra

I found in [this book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/McKaybook.pdf), on page 6 that the equation on vertices of icosahedron inscribed in sphere considered as $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by means of stereographic projection is $xy(x^{10}+14x^5y^5-y^{10})=0$.

It seems that for other polyhedra there are similar equation, so how can I simultaneously understand why all of them are integral, and can I calculate them more easily?

Comment: The question might be a little more subtle to state. The reason is if $A\in PSL_2\mathbb{C}$ and $I$ is the icosahedral group, then $AIA^{-1}$ is isomorphic to the icosahedral group, and the orbit of vertices of the corresponding icosahedron  are related to the fixed points of $I$ via the action of $A$. Let $A$ be diagonal with transcendental eigenvalues, and I don't think you are going to find an integral polynomial that vanishes exactly at those points. However, there is some integrality going on, but you need to find an invariant way of expressing it.

Comment: An appropriate answer is probably related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory